# Decrypting Multi-Prime RSA with e, N, and factors of N given

Tags: rsa, multi-prime-rsa

I was wondering if there was any way to compute the private key $d$ when knowing only $e$ and $N$, and being able to factor $N$ as 4 prime numbers $p, q, r$ and $s$. I've been searching for days and I can't find any way.

Comment: "being able to factor $N$ as 4 prime numbers $p, q, r$ and $s$" - does this mean that you know/can find the values of $p, q, r, s$, or merely that you know that $N$ has 4 factors?

Comment: I have found p, q, r and s. But I have no clue what way to go next. I've tried calculating the totient but I don't think that's the good way because I didn't get the answer I wanted.

Comment: [ the security of Multi-prime RSA is undeniably better than the standard RSA]

Comment: @user108420: are you Captain Nemo? He's quoted in [two](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7231040) [patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5848159) has having writen "RSA Moduli Should Have 3 Prime Factors" in August 1996. I wish I could locate the document. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14552/555).

Answer (score 6):

In multi-prime RSA, the definition of a valid private exponent $d$ is the same as in regular RSA: any $d$ such that $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{\lambda(N)}$, where $\lambda$ is [Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). That includes any $d$ such that $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{\varphi(N)}$, where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

With the factorization of $N$ into primes $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ known and *under the assumption that these 4 primes are distinct*, computing a valid $d$ can be done as
$$d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1,r-1,s-1)$$
or
$$d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\bigl((p-1)\,(q-1)\,(r-1)\,(s-1)\bigr)$$

---

If some of the primes are equal, we need to use more general expressions of $\lambda(N)$ or $\varphi(N)$. The simplest might be that $\varphi(N)$ is the product of factors of $N$ with the first occurrence of a unique prime replaced by one less than this prime. For example, if $p=q$ and $r=s$ and $p\ne r$, we can use
$$d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\bigl((p-1)\,q\,(r-1)\,s\bigr)$$

Also, be aware that the function $x\mapsto x^e\bmod N$ no longer is a bijection over $\Bbb Z_n$; in other words, some rare ciphertexts can correspond to multiple plaintexts. That affects plaintexts that are non-zero multiples of a prime present two times in the factorization.

For example, with

- $N=67\times71^2\times73=24655531$,
- $\varphi(N)=66\times70\times71\times72=23617440$,
- $e=13$,
- $d=10900357$, but we have the problem that
- $71^e\bmod N$ and $3125420^e\bmod N$ both are $6603710$.

---

Note: the rationale of using multi-prime RSA is to obtain speedups that require not using $d$; but using $d$ will work anyway, only slower.